# Why wget wall clock time much higher than download time?

Tags: linux, performance, shell, wget

```
wget --page-requisites --span-hosts --convert-links --adjust-extension --execute robots=off --user-agent Mozilla --random-wait https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/essential-steps-designing-empathy/
```

The command above provides the following time stats:

```
Total wall clock time: 35s
Downloaded: 248 files, 39M in 4.2s (9.36 MB/s)
```

This website takes about 5 seconds to download and display all files on a hard refresh in the browser.

Why is the wall clock time **significantly longer** than the download time and is there a way to make it faster?

I would expect the time to run the `wget command` to be roughly the same amount of time as it takes the browser to request the files. If `total_download_time` represents the total time spent downloading the files, then this matches the speed of the browser, *which would be ideal*, however, `wall_clock - total_download_time = 35s - 4.2s = 30.8s` seems like a rather excessive time to write `248 files` with cumulative size of `39M` to disk. I've also tried removing `--convert-links` and adding `--no-clobber` to the wget command and running `wget_command & wget_command` (or as many `& wget_commands` as you want process instances) in the terminal to spawn multiple processes to parallelize the download, which would more closely simulate how the browser requests files, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

The sources of `wget` are mirrored on github.

The `printf` is [here](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/main.c#L2263).

The `wall_clock` uses [`ptimer_*`](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/ptimer.c) library, implementated by wget. Scrollong down the macros, I guess on linux systems it uses `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` to measure the time. Then the difference is calculated, [start_time](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/main.c#L1365), [end_time](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/main.c#L2257) and [wall_time](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/main.c#L2258). The `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is a monotonic clock, so it represents how much time really the job has taken.

The [`total_download_time`](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/main.c#L2260) is incremented per protocol, ex. for ftp it's [here](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/ftp.c#L1573). We go then to [fd_read_body](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/retr.c#L252) and `double *elapsed` is updated [here](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/retr.c#L563) again using `ptimer_*` library, where the timer is initialized near the function entry [here](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/retr.c#L350). Guessing on what the function [does](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/retr.c#L375), the `total_download_time` probably represents only the time spend downloading the file, ie. waiting for I/O operation to complete.

Your browser is faster, because it downloads the data concurrently and doesn't write (that much) to disc. `wget` currently does not support parallel downloading.

Comment: Sincere thanks for the detailed description, but I'm still confused. If `total_download_time` represents the total time spent downloading the files, then this matches the speed of the browser, *which would be ideal*, however, `wall_clock - total_download_time = 35s - 4.2s = 30.8s` seems like a rather excessive time to write 248 files with cumulative size of **39M** to disk.

I've also tried removing `--convert-links` and adding `--no-clobber` to the wget command and running `wget_command & wget_command` in the terminal to spawn multiple processes to parallelize the download, but no success.

Comment: @JustCodin, if you want a detailed breakdown of where the time goes, `oprofile` is your friend.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, that seems very helpful. I'm trying to install `oprofile` but am experiencing many issues. I'm on mac, and first the install can't find `popt`, but `brew install popt` fixed this, but then run into a `liberty` missing library and can't find a way around it. So I spun up a couple aws instances (linux & ubuntu) and ran into the issue where `popt` was installed and not found, or renamed in the system.

Comment: oprofile depends on native Linux-kernel functionality; I wouldn't ever expect it to work on a Mac. Honestly, it's been a decade since I used it (done performance analysis work more recently than that, but against distributed systems rather than individual applications), so I'm not as current on the state of the dependency chain as I used to be.